# Using Sentri card at Global Entry point in LAX

Tags: customs-and-immigration, lax, global-entry, sentri

I've got a Sentri card but when I got to the Global Entry station at LAX I was told that I wasn't allowed to enter. This seems to be in contradiction of the "For NEXUS and SENTRI Members at Global Entry Kiosks" section on the [Global Entry website](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/global-entry/frequently-asked-questions) (though it is a bit confusing).

Does anyone have any experience with this? Can someone explain what to say so that I can use Global Entry with my Sentri card?

Comment: Did you try to use the actual card at the Global Entry kiosk? You use your passport book at the Global Entry kiosk. Cards, specifically, SENTRI, NEXUS, Global Entry, or Passport Card, are not valid for air travel into the US (two exceptions: green card and NEXUS preclearance in Canada).

Comment: @user71659 Thanks for your comment. I agree. I've amended my answer to specifically note that one must use a passport at a Global Entry kiosk,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This CBP page](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/sentri/benefits-sentri) says a Sentri card holder may use their passport at a Global Entry kiosk when entering the US by air. The page goes on to state an exception: Sentri card holders who are citizens of Mexico must specifically apply for Global Entry via their Trusted Travelers Account.

Thus, if you had arrived in the US by air, and are not a Mexican citizen, you were erroneously denied use of the kiosk.

Other than pointing out the contents of the page cited above, and perhaps having a copy of that page in your possession to show, I don't know any other approach that might allow access.